react-native text below icons goes to the second line after the sixth letter because it doesn't fit
I'm having an issue with the React Native tabs visual appearing properly.
The text I added to the _layout.tsx file with the code below goes to the bottom line as if there was no space after the fifth letter. Any ideas?
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Tabs, Link } from "expo-router";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function Layout() {
  return(
    <Tabs screenOptions={{
      headerShown: true,
      tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: 17,
        left: 6,
        right: 6,
        height: 72,
        elevation:0,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderRadius: 16,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }
    }}>
 
 <Tabs.Screen
          name="duyurular"
          options={{
            title: "Duyurular",
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#3f6600"//color you want,
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
             fontWeight: 'bold',
           },
            headerTitleAlign: "center",
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <View style={{
              alignItems: "center",
              paddingTop: 10,
              
            }}>
              <Ionicons
                name={focused ? "notifications-circle" : "notifications-circle-outline"}
                color={focused ? "#F02A4B" : "gray"}
                size={24}
              />
              <Text style={{
                color: focused ? "#F02A4B" : "gray",
                fontSize: 12,
                marginTop: 4,
              }}> Duyurular</Text>

            </View>
            )
          }}
        />



<Tabs.Screen
          name="index"
          
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <View style={{
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              height: 56,
              width: 56,
              borderRadius: 999,
              backgroundColor: "#F02A4B",
              marginBottom: 26
            }}>
              <Ionicons
                name="home"
                color="white"
                size={24}
              />
              </View>
            )
          }}
        />



<Tabs.Screen
          name="etkinlikler"
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <View style={{
              alignItems: "center",
              paddingTop: 10
            }}>
              <Ionicons
                name={focused ? "calendar-number" : "calendar-number-outline"}
                color={focused ? "#F02A4B" : "gray"}
                size={24}
              />
              <Text style={{
                color: focused ? "#F02A4B" : "gray",
                fontSize: 12,
                marginTop: 4,
              }}> Etkinlikler</Text>

            </View>
            )
          }}
        />


    </Tabs>
  )
}

it fits if I change
<Text style={{
                color: focused ? "#F02A4B" : "gray",
                fontSize: 7,
                marginTop: 4,
              }}> Duyurular</Text>

to this, bu this time text is not readable because font size is too small.
ugly tabs
I tried to fix with the flex but I was not successful.
